# Read xml file from within the JAVA project

Tags: java

I need to know where I should place the xml file inside the Java project. I need to access the placed xml file and parse it. I have tried using resources folder but its not working out for me. Can someone suggest me a good idea on how to access the xml file which is placed within the JAVA project. I am using Eclipse IDE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the structure of maven : Project/src/main/resources

I suppose it is a data xml file. If it is a config file a better way is to access it via the classpath.
This is a common place where to put the resources, but you can choose your own directory. If you have problem to open the file, it is your path which is not correct. Try first to open it with a absolute path. Something like d:/workspace/Project/src/main/resources/file.xml. It will works.

Answer (score 2):

use like below class --

```
this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("path of file");
```

NOTE : this xml file structure in project

```
+pro
   +src
   +resource
     -test.xml
```

Example:

```
 public class ReadFile {
        public void testReadFile() {
            InputStream in = this.getClass().getClassLoader()
            .getResourceAsStream("/Resources/tset.xml");
//praparing DOM
        DocumentBuilderFactory docBuilderFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory
                .newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder docBuilder = docBuilderFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
// by sending input stream as input to DOM
        Document doc = docBuilder.parse(in);
        }
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            ReadFile file = new ReadFile();
            file.testReadFile();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Apart from some typos your answer helped me. +1

Answer (score 1):

resources folder is the correct folder to place your xml file. If it is not finding the file in that folder, then it may not be on classpath. So, add this folder to your project's classpath.

Go to Project -> Properties -> Java Build Path -> Source -> Add Folder

Then add the resources folder to your classpath. Thats all...You are good to go..

Comment: Where should I create the resoures folder. Is it within the packege where the java source file is or under src.

Comment: is your project maven project or simple webapp or java project?

Comment: Java project. But what do you mean about maven project.

Comment: I have src folder in which, I have a package named com.sample.parsexml/JAVA FILE. where should I create the resources folder here

Comment: you can place resource folder anywhere as long as you add it to your classpath. I suggest make resource folder parallel to your src folder.

Comment: means resource folder is sibbling of src folder

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure that Eclipse includes /resources folder into the application classpath.

Open your launcher from `Run Configurations`, goto `Classpath` tab and if it's not there - add it.

The file can be read with `this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource*` methods.